# Can I use this list to feed an Arrayadapter?

Tags: android, arrays, adapter, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

Can I use the code below to feed my adapter? If so, any idea how cause I seem kinda stuck. If not, is there another way to setup the arraylist so I do get 3 options per page without having to make a new class/arraylist for each food. (might be a large amount of classes if thats the only way)

I set it up like this because each button will have a different time value to put trough to the next page.

(in example) If, on the previous page, user selects the item "artichoke" than a new page should load with the 3 buttons mildly, medium & well done (which will also have different boiling times each).

```
   package diederik.lucas.boiltime.data;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TimeOneData {


    private List<Time> Times = new ArrayList<Time>();
    public List<Time> getTimes() {
        return Times;       
    }

    //Not sure if void is the correct return value here
    public void asparagus() {
        addItem(new Time ("Mildly","6"));
        addItem(new Time ("Medium","8"));
        addItem(new Time ("Well Done","10"));
    }

    //Not sure if void is the correct return value here
    public void artichoke() {
        addItem(new Time ("Mildly","5"));
        addItem(new Time ("Medium","7"));
        addItem(new Time ("Well Done","9"));
    }


    //Not sure if void is the correct return value here
    public void beetroot() {
        addItem(new Time ("Mildly","7"));
        addItem(new Time ("Medium","10"));
        addItem(new Time ("Well Done","13"));
    }

    //Not sure if void is the correct return value here
    public void broadBeans() {
        addItem(new Time ("Mildly","1"));
        addItem(new Time ("Medium","2"));
        addItem(new Time ("Well Done","3"));

    }   //Not sure if void is the correct return value here
    public void broccolli() {
        addItem(new Time ("Mildly","4"));
        addItem(new Time ("Medium","8"));
        addItem(new Time ("Well Done","12"));

    }   //Not sure if void is the correct return value here
    public void cabbage() {
        addItem(new Time ("Mildly","3"));
        addItem(new Time ("Medium","6"));
        addItem(new Time ("Well Done","9"));
    }





    private void addItem(Time item) {
        Times.add(item);
    }


}
```

Context: I am a beginner trying to learn Java + android app building. Please try to keep this in mind if you are kind enough to write me an answer! ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an Enum to structure your data. As Enums are objects [they can have attributes and methods](http://javahowto.blogspot.co.il/2008/04/java-enum-examples.html), you can set up a VegetableTime enum having an ArrayList of times attribute.

Then you can use that and if you need a list, you can get them by using VegetableTime.values();

By the way, "Mildly" & co should also be an enum (that could sit in Time class).

Code example, here's a way to define what is a CookingTime with it's two parameters.

```
public class CookingTime {

    public enum Preparation {

        MILDLY, MEDIUM, WELL_DONE;
    }

    private int time;
    private Preparation preparation;

    CookingTime(Preparation preparation, int time){

        this.time = time;
        this.preparation = preparation;
    }
}
```

And here's a Vegetable with inline creation of the right list for this cooking.

```
public enum Vegetable {

    ASPARGUS(Arrays.asList(new CookingTime(CookingTime.Preparation.MILDLY, 8), new CookingTime(CookingTime.Preparation.WELL_DONE, 15)));

    Vegetable(List<CookingTime> cookingTimes){
        this.cookingTimes = cookingTimes;
    }

    private List<CookingTime> cookingTimes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Ok, sounds like a good idea;) Gonna work on this.I ll report back soon...

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I came up with:

```
Enum:
```

public enum FoodTimeEnum{

```
ASPARAGUS ("2",  "3", "4"),
ARTICHOKE ("8",  "12", "16");
//more veggies


private final String mildly;
private final String medium;
private final String welldone;

private FoodTimeEnum(String mildly, String medium, String welldone) {
    this.mildly = mildly;
    this.medium = medium;
    this.welldone = welldone;
}

public String getMildly() {
    return mildly;
}

public String getMeduim() {
    return medium;
}

public String getWelldone(){
    return welldone;
}
```

}

and in the Timeclass

```
public class Time {
    public String timeName;
    public String timeMildly;
    public String timeMedium;
    public String timeLong;



    public Time(String id, String boilTime, String mildly, String medium, String welldone) { 
        this.timeName = id;
        this.timeMildly = mildly;
        this.timeMedium = medium;
        this.timeLong = welldone;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return timeName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Added some code on my answer, please check out. Your code is making me wonder if you wouldn't need some fortifications on your Oriented Programming basis... ?

Comment: Oh yes, I do. I am writing this app to learn. I am a beginner, I have spend a lot of time reading but I need experience writing. I am  also trying to practise coding by making simple setups, although this is my first real app. project. Big thanks for the code up there and giving this greenhorn some help!

Comment: Maybe you're jumping ahead too fast then! Usually when learning Java, you can make a multi class game in command line, and when your OO basis is stronger, do an android app. Or maybe doing android gives you that motivation, so kudos to you and good luck!

Comment: Yeah I was doing android cause it gives you...more fun;) But yes, very big jumps are involved. So I already figured to repeat the basics again before going further. A game in the command line. I ll take a look into that:P thanks again!